# Error send email

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendmail

I have just 1 controller without view or model, how can I fix this?

change 1
[image]

change 2
[image]

Comment: Use `$ci =& get_instance();` instead `$ci =get_instance();`

Comment: You probably have to enable SSL on your php.ini `extension=php_openssl.dll`

Comment: See my Final solution..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function Send_mail()
{
    $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
     'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
     'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
   );
   $this->load->library('email', $config);
  $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('blabla@gmail.com', 'something');
    $this->email->to('blabla2@gmail.com'); 

    $this->email->subject('bla bla');
    $this->email->message('whatever.');  

    $this->email->send();

    echo $this->email->print_debugger();


}
```

Comment: you are not even using the code that I provided. How can i know the output?

Answer (score 0):

r u sure send mail functionality working your local system?

Please check simple mail function first in your local system then after you will check  CodeIgniter send mail functionality

and if now if any error will be coming then check below

`phpinfo();` SSL is on or not in php.ini.

Thanks